# glassfish smtp from name

Tags: java, email, glassfish-4

We use a GlassFish server (JavaEE 7) with JavaMail.
Afaik, the official E-Mail RFC states that mail addresses may look something like this:

```
Tom Tester <tom.tester@test.com>
```

which would include a nicer representation than using only the email address. The Glassfish server is able to use this when configuring it on the admin console, clients like the GMail web client then display "Tom Tester" as sender. However, I'd like to specify the mail resource in the `glassfish-resources.xml` within our project, the configuration file doesn't allow `<` or `>`, because it's xml. I tried

```
<mail-resource 
    from="Tom Tester &lt;tom.tester@test.com&gt;"
    ...
```

and

```
<mail-resource 
    from="Tom Tester tom.tester@test.com"
        ...
```

, but these configurations won't work. Both approaches end up in sending only "tom.tester@test.com" as sender. I also didn't find any specification details from the GlassFish docs. Does somebody know if the desired behaviour is possible?

Comment: "won't work" doesn't give much information - what happens when you try those?

Comment: sorry, i added the information. just "tom.tester@test.com" is being set as sender in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to explicitly set the personal name for the sender, you need to do it while creating the email message.

Let's say you have the session `mailSession` from the GlassFish Resource and you are creating a message `mailMessage`

Now you can set the `from` attribute of the message:

```
mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailSession.getProperty("mail.from"), "Tom Tester"));
```

Read more [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sending-email-using-javamail).